# Refactored models, now celery won't start

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I have a django app called "uar" and I refactored the `uar/models.py` so that there are base classes in `uar_common/models.py` - for instance instead of

```
class ReviewPerson(models.Model):
```

I have

```
class ReviewPerson(uar_common.models.CommonPerson):
```

I added `uar_common` to the INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py, and my app works fine. But my celery tasks, which worked fine in the past, don't work any more. I start it with `python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=debug` as always, but now it dies immediately with a stack trace that ends with:

```
File "/home/ptomblin/src/cart/uar/models.py", line 8, in <module>
  class ReviewPerson(uar_common.models.CommonPerson):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'models'
```

If I just run `python manage.py shell`, I can do

```
from uar.models import ReviewPerson
rp = ReviewPerson.objects.get(review=2, last_name='Tomblin', first_name='Paul')
```

and it has no problem importing the model and find the correct record.

So why can't djcelery find the new base class?

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to CELERY_IMPORTS

```
'uar_common.models',
'uar_history.models',
```

And now it's working.